# Get the child category ID of current category

Tags: wp-query, categories

I am trying to get the category ID of the child (no grand children) of the current category. Using below method:

```
$category = get_category(get_query_var( 'cat' ));
// get category ID
$catid = $category->cat_ID;
```

I can get the current category ID. However, using this in `WP_Query` result in displaying the posts that are published in Parent, Child, Grand Child category.

Is there any way, to get the child category ID of the current category?

**Update #1:**

Sample category structure is as follow:

```
- Parent Category x
-- Child One
--- Grand Child one
--- Grand Child two
-- Child Two
--- Grand Child one
--- Grand Child two
```

once in the `Parent Category x` we have the ID, now I want the `Child Category id`. Once in `Child Category x`, I want the `Grand Child Category id` to be used in :

```
wordpresss/category/parent       : posts published in child category 
wordpresss/category/parent/child : posts published in grand child category
```

Comment: is this on a category archive page?

Comment: @milo yes, I am trying to create a custom query which displays posts published under the sub category (not the parent or grand child category)

Comment: so, there are multiple levels of child categories under the parent and you only want the level directly below?

Comment: @Milo I updated the question, but basically yes, the below category of current category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) with `parent` argument to get only direct children of a term. Use [`wp_list_pluck`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) to extract an array of term IDs that can be passed to a query.

```
$args = array(
    'parent' => get_queried_object_id(),
); 

$terms = get_terms( 'category', $args );

$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
```

Also uses [`get_queried_object_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to get the ID of the current category archive.

Comment: so something like [this](http://pastebin.com/9WKHWeYr) ?

Comment: `$term_ids` is already an array, no need to wrap it in `array()`.

Comment: nice, it worked :) one quick question, is it possible to test if we are in the last category so instead of linking to category we link to post?

Comment: You can check if `$terms` is `empty`, there are no child terms.